# Cannot Attach Kernel Mode Debugger to Process in debugging KMDF driver

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, driver, wdk

I am currently trying to build a simple Win 7 x64 USB driver using this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh706187(v=vs.85).aspx

Host is using VS2013 & WDK 8.1

Because I don't have a null-modem cable (or any other means of setting up a debugger connection between host and target), I just filled my settings with the default ones found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh698272(v=vs.85).aspx), expecting some sort of error to return, but the configuration process went through without a hitch, displaying

```
WDK Remote User Account successfully created
Installing .NET Framework 9possible reboot)
Installing VC Redist (x64)
Installing test automation (x86)
Installing test automation (x64)
Installing debuggers (x86)
Installing debuggers (x64)
Installing driver test framewok
Registering logging components
Configure debugger settings (x64) (possible reboot)
Configure computer settings (x64) (possible reboot)
Creating system restore point
Complete
```

So I assumed that what I assumed about serial/com ports to be wrong and continued to attach the WKM Debugger to 'Kernel' of my target computer, which was listed under the "Available Processes" datagrid. When I click the 'Attach' button, however, I get an error that says:

```
Windows Debugging Extension for Visual Studio

Could not start debug session, error 80070002: The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried Building/Rebuilding the project many times, and Provisioning the target computer also multiple times to the same results. I saw that question number 25776839 also had the same issue as me, but he mentioned something about changing VS's default from Kernel Debugger to Remote Debugger, which I'm not sure how that can be accomplished, but also caused other problems. I've also tried to "attach process" using the same setting via WinDBG but did not produce anything useful.

Also, I switched from MSVS2015 and WDK10 to MSVS2013 and WDK8.1 because their tutorial files led me to missing header files (warning.h many others), and package files.

Can anyone show me what I did wrong or what I need to do to fix the 80070002 error? Yes, I am new to driver dev.

Comment: I feel your pain. It was a nightmare trying to deploy and test driver with VS 2013, so now I just stick to WinDbg. Is it safe to assume that your target computer is a virtual machine? If so, how did you configure the machine? Also, what are the arguments you used for WinDbg? It should look something like this: `windbg -k "com:port=\\.\pipe\com_1,baud=115200,pipe,reconnect"`

Comment: @tchau.dev Alright, I was severely mistaken. I was under the assumption that because I was presented all the connection options in provisioning, provisioning took place over those settings. Rereading through the instructions, I realize now that it took place over my active **Private Network**. My host computer is a separate laptop, and I do not right now have means of setting up a KMD connection. When I get my hands on new hardware, I will give update on my situation; and assuming there is no further issues, this probably is the reason why I kept getting error 80070002 (lack of source files)